# c++ set data structure which keeps inserted order

Tags: c++, boost, data-structures, set

Is there any C++ built-in set data structure which keeps the inserted order?
It doesn't a problem whether the set is a hash set or a set implemented by a balanced binary tree.

Comment: Take a look at [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **C++11**, both `std::multiset` and `std::multimap` are guaranteed to preserve the insertion order of same-valued/same-keyed elements.

Quoting from the C++11 standard,

> #### 23.2.4 Associative containers
>
> <sup>4</sup> An associative container supports unique keys if it may contain at most one element for each key. Otherwise,
>   it supports equivalent keys. The set and map classes support unique keys; the multiset and multimap classes
>   support equivalent keys. **For `multiset` and `multimap`, insert, emplace, and erase preserve the relative
>   ordering of equivalent elements**.

It must be explicitly stated that their unordered (hash) variants, `std::unordered_multiset` and `std::unordered_multimap` **does not** guarantee (it is unspecified) the relative order of insertion of elements.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure if I understand what you are asking, but it sounds to me like a linked list would sufficiently suit your needs.  You can just push and pop to keep the list in the order you placed it in.  You can look here for a reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

Furthermore, you can use the unique method to remove duplicates making it emulate a set data structure.

Comment: no. I need a data structure like a linked hash map(in java) which gives searching performance like a hash map and gives ability to iterate through the items in inserted order

Comment: It is not ideal, but you can use list then. Using list, you can push all your items to the back of the list using push_back. Then, before iterating, use unique (ensures that it is a set).  Finally, you can iterate through the list, starting from the beginning thereby maintaining order, using the iterator provided.

...Unless I am wrong about what you are asking, which just like in my comment, is a distict possiblity.

Comment: First, I have mentioned "set data structure".
In c++ set and unordered set, both have better performance in searching. Because STL set uses a binary tree and unordered set is using hashing. I want performance in searching and an opportunity of retrieving the order.

Answer (score 1):

Boost guarantees that all associative containers preserve insertion ordering.

> a_eq.insert(t): If a range containing elements equivalent to t exists in a_eq, t is inserted at the end of that range.

ref: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/container/cpp_conformance.html#container.cpp_conformance.insertion_hints